# Поиск значений из списка в xml

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

Помогите завершить код?!
Из списка в `txt` искать значения в теге `<xxx>`
Если нашли вхождение, то забрать всё между тегами `<person>` `</person>`.
Такие найденыши сохранить в `result.xml` с сохранением всей структуры `xml`

Это xml файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<id>
<tag1></tag1>
<tag2></tag2>
<tag3></tag3>
<persons>
    <person><fio></fio><age></age><xxx></xxx><city></city><bd></bd></person>
    <person><fio></fio><age></age><xxx></xxx><city></city><bd></bd></person>
    <person><fio></fio><age></age><xxx></xxx><city></city><bd></bd></person>
</persons>
</id>
```

А это код c#

```
var eee = XElement.Load(@"file.xml");
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"file.txt"))
{
    foreach (var s in eee.Descendants("xxx"))
       if (s.Value.Contains(line))
        {

// Если значение из txt найдено в теге <xxx>, то забрать всё между тегами <person> </person>
// и сохранять в  result.xml с сохранением всей структуры xml


        }

}
eee.Save(@"result.xml");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто создайте результирующий документ, и перекидывайте в него ноды, подходящие под условие:

```
XElement result = new XElement("persons");

var eee = XElement.Load(@"file.xml");
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"file.txt"))
{
    foreach (var s in eee.Descendants("xxx"))
    {
        if (s.Value.Contains(line))
        {
            result.Add(s.Parent);
        }
    }
}
result.Save(@"result.xml");
```

Comment: Ой, а структура `XML` сохраняется не полностью. Теги от самого начала до `<persons>` не переносятся в `result.xml`

Comment: @Андрей тогда может быть вам стоит переформулировать вопрос и пересмотреть подход? например, не искать ноды которые надо перенести (как сейчас предполагается в вопросе и в моем ответе), а искать ноды которые надо удалить?

Comment: Ну, у меня в txt желаемое, не знаю получится ли удалять ненужные...в xml